# How to fix alerts

Tags: swift, xcode

I've written a function to output alerts, but it doesn't work.

Here's the function:

```
if titleTextField.text.isEmpty == false {
            if let result = DataManager.shared.quizController.joinQuiz(id: titleTextField.text) {
                switch result {
                case .badCode :
                    self.showErrorAlert(message: "Bad code")
                case .joined:
                    self.showErrorAlert(message: "You are alredy joined")
                case .notJoined:
                    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

I expect this to output some alerts, however I'm not getting any output at all.

Comment: Hey there & welcome to StackOverflow. To better understand your question, we need to see more code. To begin, what's `showErrorAlert(message:)` do and how is it implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way of showing alert

```
if titleTextField.text.isEmpty == false {
            if let result = DataManager.shared.quizController.joinQuiz(id: titleTextField.text) {
                switch result {
                case .badCode :
                    self.showErrorAlert(message: "Bad code")
                case .joined:
                    self.showErrorAlert(message: "You are alredy joined")
                case .notJoined:
                    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
                }
       }
//function for showing alert message

    func showErrorAlert(_ with message: String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```